# Facebook not working in localhost

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I need to integrate Facebook login on my website .I have added localhost.com,localhost in App Domains setting in facebook app  and also set https://localhost/mysocial/socialmedia/login/Facebook in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs  I got following error .

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

How can I fix .

Comment: Soni, You should try @GhostfromTexas' answer. He is right.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost.com" isn't going to get you anything.

You need the full URL to callback with your oauth. Generally with Oauth you'll have something to the effect of...

> mydomain.com/auth/facebook/callback

This is the endpoint setup to handle the callback from Facebook or other sites back to your app once the authorization is complete. This needs to be your redirect URL in your app settings on Facebook.

I specifically wrote our OAuth system where I work, and we integrated Facebook, so I've been through this exact thing.

This is our settings for local host redirect:

> https://i.gyazo.com/c67a3043c4b397f78d5a77295a0f8a9d.png

Good luck!

Comment: I have changed my Valid OAuth Redirect URIs as "https://127.0.0.1:8080/idashboard/socialmedia/login/Facebook".

Comment: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: the https request is needed on the website, they change it just last march